# szExeFile in PROCESSENTERY32 stucture gives a weird value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, process

Wen I try to list all names and Id's of currently running processes I get some weird results when I try to cout the process's szExeFile. 
Here is what I get:

```
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 0
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 4
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 392
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 508
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 588
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 596
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 648
Process name: 005BF3EC and id: 684
```

Here is the CODE:

```
HANDLE ProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);  
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe = {0};
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);



        if (ProcSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            cout << "Can't make a snapshot" << endl;
        }


        Process32First(ProcSnap, &pe);
        do {

            cout << "Process name: " <<pe.szExeFile<< " and id: " << pe.th32ProcessID << endl;


        } while (Process32Next(ProcSnap, &pe));
```

Answer (score 6):

You have defined `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` in your project settings. The `TCHAR` array in the [PROCESSENTRY32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684839.aspx) structure therefore expands to a `wchar_t` array. There is no overload for `cout` that takes a `const wchar_t*`, hence it uses the generic pointer implementation, and displays the pointer value.

You should use `std::wcout` instead.

Note: While it is possible to invoke the ANSI version of the API, those are only kept around for compatibility with Win9x. They perform lossy conversions, from ANSI to Unicode (and vice versa), and waste resources. Unless there is a real reason to call the ANSI versions, don't.

Fixed code:

```
HANDLE ProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);  
if (ProcSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    wcout << L"Can't make a snapshot" << endl;
}

PROCESSENTRY32W pe = {0};
pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
if (Process32FirstW(ProcSnap, &pe)) {
    do {
        wcout << L"Process name: " << pe.szExeFile
              << L" and id: " << pe.th32ProcessID << endl;
    } while (Process32NextW(ProcSnap, &pe));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` is not designed for printing `wchar_t*` strings, instead that use `std::wcout`, or do not use multibyte and unicode strings in your project. Also, mixing `std::wcout` and `std::cout` is illegale.

If you want to use in this code section ANSI version of function, add to the name `A` postfix, for example `Process32First` will be changed by compiler if defined `_UNICODE` to `Process32FirstW`, but you can directly call `Process32FirstA`.

Comment: Thanks. Divided in 2 operations wcout and cout

Comment: `Process32First` expands to `Process32FirstW`, if the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined (the `UNICODE` symbol controls the Windows API, the `_UNICODE` symbol the CRT). There is no symbol called `Process32FirstA`, so you cannot call it (and it would be a bad idea anyway).